# Division using right shift operator gives TLE while normal division works fine

Tags: c++

I'm trying to submit this [leetcode problem Pow(x,n)](https://leetcode.com/problems/powx-n/) using iterative approach.

```
double poww(double x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    double ans = 1;
    double temp = x;
    while (n)
    {
        if (n & 1)
        {
            ans *= temp;
        }
        temp *= temp;
        n = (n >> 1);
    }
    return ans;
}
double myPow(double x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1.0;
    if (n < 0)
        return 1 / poww(x, abs(n));
    return poww(x, n);
}
```

This code is giving time limit exceed error but when I change the right shift operator `>>` with normal division operator, the code works just fine.

Working code with division operator

```
double poww(double x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    double ans = 1;
    double temp = x;
    while (n)
    {
        if (n & 1)
        {
            ans *= temp;
        }
        temp *= temp;
        n /= 2;
    }
    return ans;
}
double myPow(double x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1.0;
    if (n < 0)
        return 1 / poww(x, abs(n));
    return poww(x, n);
}
```

I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Build locally on your own system (with optimizations enabled). Compare the generated assembly.

Comment: Also, bitwise operations on signed integers (and `int` is a signed integer type) can lead to all kind of problems. Especially if the values happen to be negative. Division is well-defined and produces expected results when using negative numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the given input range for "n".

Let us look at the constraints again:

[image]

The problem is the smallest number for n, which is -2^31 and that is equal to -2147483648.

But the valid range for an integer is -2^31 ... 2^31-1 which is -2147483648 ... 2147483647.

Then you try to use the abs function on -2147483648. But since there is no positive  equivalent for that in the integer domain (on your machine), the number stays negative. And then you get the wrong result, because your n will be negative in your "poww" function.

Presumably on your machine `long` is the same as `int`, so, a 4 byte variable. If you change your interface to use a `long long` variable, it will work. Result maybe "inf" for big numbers or 0.

Please check the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

long double poww(double x, long long n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    long double ans = 1;
    long double temp = x;
    while (n)
    {
        if (n & 1)
        {
            ans *= temp;
        }
        temp *= temp;
        n = (n >> 1);
    }
    return ans;
}
long double myPow(double x, long long n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1.0;
    if (n < 0) 
        return 1 / poww(x, std::llabs(n));
    return poww(x, n);
}
int main() {
    std::cout << myPow(1, -2147483648) << '\n';
}
```